# Changing text in crafty.js

Tags: javascript, html, dom, craftyjs

I have two variables (the enemies and players helath) that change when a certain event happens, the problem is that I dont know how to change text, or remove text, so I cant change the displayed health on the screen (currently I am just placing the new health ontop of the old one). Here is the relevant component.

```
//player character during combat
//This also controls player input during combat and resolves most of the combat
//Will display and take inputs for quesions eventually
Crafty.c('BattlePlayer', {
init:function() {
var OpPos = 1;
var HealthPas = 100 + ',' + 100;
var FightOver = false;
//Displays options for the first time with attack selected
this.requires('Actor, spr_BattlePlayer, SpriteAnimation, Keyboard')
.bind('KeyDown', function () { if (this.isDown('SPACE')) Crafty.scene('World');})
.bind('KeyDown', function () { if (this.isDown('ENTER')) HealthPas =    this.BattleSelect(OpPos, HealthPas, FightOver);})
.bind('KeyDown', function () { if (this.isDown('S')) if (OpPos < 3){OpPos = OpPos +  1}; this.MenuMove(OpPos); })
.bind('KeyDown', function () { if (this.isDown('W')) if (OpPos > 1) {OpPos = OpPos - 1}; this.MenuMove(OpPos); });


Crafty.e('2D, DOM, Text')
.attr({ x: 200, y: 150 })
.text(100);

Crafty.e('2D, DOM, Text')
.attr({ x: 200, y: 100 })
.text(100);

Crafty.e('AttackSel').at(3,8);
Crafty.e('DefendUnsel').at(3,13);
Crafty.e('RunUnsel').at(3,18);

var MenuPos = 1;    

},
//function for displaying what option is currently selected
MenuMove: function(OpPos) {
switch (OpPos)
{
case 1:
//Attack case
Crafty.e('AttackSel').at(3,8);
Crafty.e('DefendUnsel').at(3,13);
Crafty.e('RunUnsel').at(3,18);
break;

case 2:
//Defend case
Crafty.e('AttackUnsel').at(3,8);
Crafty.e('DefendSel').at(3,13);
Crafty.e('RunUnsel').at(3,18);
break;

case 3:
//Run case
Crafty.e('AttackUnsel').at(3,8);
Crafty.e('DefendUnsel').at(3,13);
Crafty.e('RunSel').at(3,18);
break;

default:
//Incorrect input case
Crafty.e('AttackUnsel').at(3,8);
Crafty.e('DefendUnsel').at(3,13);
Crafty.e('RunUnsel').at(3,18);
}
},

//function for carrying out battle options
//Within this function Num[0] represents players health and Nums[1] represents the Enemy Health.
BattleSelect: function(OpPos, HealthPas, FightOver) {
var Nums = HealthPas.split(',');
Crafty.e('2D, DOM, Text')
.attr({ x: 200, y: 150 })
.text(Nums[0]);

switch (OpPos)
{
case 1:
//Attack case
if (FightOver == false)
{
Nums[1] = Nums[1] - 20;
Crafty.e('2D, DOM, Text')
.attr({ x: 200, y: 100 })
.text(Nums[1]);
Crafty.audio.play('attack');
this.EndCheck(Nums[0], Nums[1], FightOver);
Nums[0] = Nums[0] - 10;
}
break;

case 2:
//Heal case
//as this was originaly a string, minus 1 to change it to an integer
Nums[0] = Nums[0] - 1 + 21;
this.EndCheck(Nums[0], Nums[1], FightOver);
break;

case 3:
//Run case
//switch checks what room the player is in the transport them back there
switch (Location)
{
case 1:
Crafty.scene('World');
break;

case 2:
Crafty.scene('HubWorld');
break;

case 3:
Crafty.scene('Yr10Tp1');
break;

case 3.1:
Crafty.scene('Yr10Tp1_1');
break;

case 3.11:
Crafty.scene('Yr10Tp1_1.1');
break;

case 3.12:
Crafty.scene('Yr10Tp1_1.2');
break;

case 3.2:
Crafty.scene('Yr10Tp1_2');
break;

case 3.3:
Crafty.scene('Yr10Tp1_1.3');
break;

case 4:
Crafty.scene('Yr10Tp2');
break;

case 5:
Crafty.scene('Yr10Tp3');
break;

case 6:
Crafty.scene('Yr11Tp1');
break;

case 7:
Crafty.scene('Yr11Tp2');
break;

case 8:
Crafty.scene('Yr11Tp3');
break;

default:
Crafty.scene('World');
}

default:
this.EndCheck(Nums[0], Nums[1]);
Nums[0] = Nums[0] - 10;
}
HealthPas = Nums[0] + ',' + Nums[1];
return HealthPas;
},

//function to check for winning conditions
EndCheck : function(PlayerHealth, EnemyHealth, FightOver)
{

if (EnemyHealth < 1)
    {
    FightOver = true;
    monsterBeat = true;
    }
else if (PlayerHealth < 1)
    {
    FightOver = true;
    }

if (FightOver == true)
{
Crafty.e('2D, DOM, Text')
.attr({ x: 500, y: 150 })
.text('Victory!');
}
return FightOver;   
},
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure to look at [the documentation for text](http://craftyjs.com/api/Text.html#-text).

To set the text directly, you just call the `text` method of the entity.  So whenever the base property changes, you could do this -- either by calling the method directly, or setting up an "UpdateHealth" event.

So, a text component might look like this:

```
Crafty.e('2D, DOM, Text')
  .attr({ x: 200, y: 150 })
  .text(Nums[0]);
  .bind("UpdatePlayerHealth", function(health){this.text(health)});
```

And then when the player took damage, it would trigger that event with code that looks something like this:

```
Crafty.trigger("UpdatePlayerHealth", this.health);
```

The advantage of using events like this is that you don't need to carry around a reference to the text object, and you could modify other aspects of the game when a player's health changed.

If you wanted, you could pass more info in the event by using an object, such as:

```
Crafty.trigger("UpdatePlayerHealth", {health: this.health, damage: damageValue});
```

(Although of course you'd also need to adjust the bound function on the text display, since it would be passed an object rather than just a number.)

Comment: thanks for the help! one more step towards somewhat understanding crafty!